# Loading jqGrid using json data in vb.net

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, vb.net, jqgrid

So,I am serialising a list of objects to load into a jqGrid.But unfortunately,I keep getting an error and I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

I am using ADO.NET to get the data from the database and serialize that data.The code is as shown below.this code is present in LoadGridContent method used in ajax call

```
    Dim serializer As New JavaScriptSerializer()
    Dim JsonString As String
    JsonString = serializer.Serialize(lstPatients)
    Return serializer.Serialize(lstPatients)
```

The serialised output is as shown below

```
 [{"LastName":"Doe","FirstName":"Jane","MiddleName1":"S","MiddleName2":"","PatientID":24511,"OtherID":"erw","SSN":"992-33-7878","Photopath":"","GenderID":1,"HomePhone":"(770) 555-    8787","PrimaryPhone":"(770) 555-   8787","PrimaryWorkPhone":"","PatientBalance":0,"InsuranceBalance":0,"TotalCredit":0,"PatientStatusID":0},
  {"LastName":"Doe","FirstName":"John","MiddleName1":"","MiddleName2":"","PatientID":26209,"OtherID":"","SSN":"159-75-   3259","Photopath":"","GenderID":2,"HomePhone":"","PrimaryPhone":"","PrimaryWorkPhone":"","PatientBalance":0,"InsuranceBalance":0,"TotalCredit":0,"PatientStatusID":0},
  {"LastName":"Doe","FirstName":"John","MiddleName1":"A.","MiddleName2":"","PatientID":19395,"OtherID":"erw","SSN":"977-33-2456","Photopath":"","GenderID":2,"HomePhone":"(770) 555-8787","PrimaryPhone":"(678) 555-0366","PrimaryWorkPhone":"(678) 555-0366","PatientBalance":0,"InsuranceBalance":0,"TotalCredit":0,"PatientStatusID":0}]
```

And my ajax code to load the grid on click of a button is as follows.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnSearch").click(function () {
        debugger;
        var lastname = document.getElementById("txtLastName").value
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "PatientSearchModify/LoadGridContent",
            data: "{}",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (result) {
                result = result.d
                jQuery("jqGridPatientSearch").jqGrid({
                    datatype: "local",
                    colNames: ['PatientId', 'LastName', 'FirstName', 'MiddleName', 'SSN',
                    'Sex', "Other ID", 'Home Phone', 'Work Phone', 'Patient Balance', 'Insurance Balance', 'Total Credit'],
                    colModel: [
            { name: 'PatientId', index: 'PatientId', width: 20, stype: 'text', sortable: true },
            { name: 'LastName', index: 'LastName', width: 150, sortable: true },
            { name: 'FirstName', index: 'FirstName', width: 150, sortable: true },
            { name: 'MiddleName1', index: 'MiddleName', width: 100, sortable: true },
            { name: 'SSN', index: 'SSN', width: 80, sortable: true },
            { name: 'GenderID', index: 'GenderID', width: 40, sortable: true },
            { name: 'OtherID', index: 'OtherID', width: 80, sortable: true },
            { name: 'HomePhone', index: 'HomePhone', width: 150, sortable: false },
            { name: 'PrimaryWorkPhone', index: 'PrimaryWorkPhone', width: 100, sortable: false },
            { name: 'PatientBalance', index: 'PatientBalance', width: 100, sortable: false },
            { name: 'InsuranceBalance', index: 'InsuranceBalance', width: 100, sortable: false },
            { name: 'TotalCredit', index: 'TotalCredit', width: 100, sortable: false },
            ],
                    data: JSON.parse(result),
                    rowNum: 10,
                    sortname: 'PatientId',
                    loadonce: true,
                    viewrecords: true,
                    sortorder: "asc",
                    caption: "Patient Search"
                });
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert(error)
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Even though all the data seems to be correct,for the life of me I am not able to figure out,why the grid is not getting loaded.Everytime an error is thrown.